# XCode7 ui testing: How to swipe a certain location?

Tags: xcode, swipe, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I want to swipe a screen to the left. But I have no label or button whose display-label does not change or is recognizeable during recording. So I cannot find a point to grab and swipe the screen.

Is there a possibility to swipe a certain screen-coordinate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to swipe a particular distance or to a particular point on the scroll view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just solved it by recording a tap on a random screen location. This gave me three lines of `app.childrenMatchingType(.Window).elmentBoundByIndex(0).....element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).tap()`

Somehow weird. But I changed `tap()` with `swipeLeft()` and it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

You can swipe directly on the app, and even the window.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.swipeLeft()
app.windows.element.swipeLeft()
```

Comment: That does not work somehow. The test is always crashing when I attempt to swipe like this